# Splitting Name into First and Last Name and then Counting Last Name to Determine Family Size in Pandas-- How to Deal with NaN?

Tags: pandas, count, nan

friends,
I am pretty new to Pandas and hoped for some advice.
I have a data frame with a column of names.  I want to split the names to create a new column of last names, and then create a new column which gives family size (the number of occurrences of the last name).  (I realize that some family members don't share a last name and that some people with the same last name are not related, so the proxy is not perfect.)  The problem I am running into is a number of the names are Nan, so when I do the count, the family size for the Nan is the total number of missing values.  I'd like the count to exclude the Nan individuals.

Here is a toy example-- I would like for the Family Size of the nan rows not to be 2, but to be nan.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Hilary Clinton', 'Bob Dole', 'nan', 'Chelsea Clinton', 'Eizabeth Dole', 'nan'],    'State': ['New York', 'Kansas', 'Vermont', 'California', 'Kansas', 'California']})

#  create new LastName column and put last name in it by splitting the string
df['LastName'] = df['Name'].str.split().str[-1]
#  check that it worked as expected
df.head()
df['FamilySize']=df.groupby('LastName')['LastName'].transform('count')
```

Output

Out[12]:
Name       State LastName  FamilySize
0   Hilary Clinton    New York  Clinton           2
1         Bob Dole      Kansas     Dole           2
2              nan     Vermont      nan           2
3  Chelsea Clinton  California  Clinton           2
4    Eizabeth Dole      Kansas     Dole           2
5              nan  California      nan           2

I tried the code listed above.  I have read a lot about group.by, and wonder if there is a different way to count by last name.

Comment: Kaggle Titanic?

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much there. Convert your 'nan' strings into actual `nan` values (for instance, replace 'nan' with `pandas.NA`). Then, exclude NAs from your groupby with `dropna=True`:

```
>>> df['FamilySize']=df.groupby('LastName', dropna=True)['LastName'].transform('count')

|   |            Name |      State | LastName | FamilySize |
|--:|----------------:|-----------:|---------:|-----------:|
| 0 |  Hilary Clinton |   New York |  Clinton |        2.0 |
| 1 |        Bob Dole |     Kansas |     Dole |        2.0 |
| 2 |            <NA> |    Vermont |     <NA> |        NaN |
| 3 | Chelsea Clinton | California |  Clinton |        2.0 |
| 4 |   Eizabeth Dole |     Kansas |     Dole |        2.0 |
| 5 |            <NA> | California |     <NA> |        NaN |
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a data encoding problem. **You must pay attention to data types**. Failure to do so will result in misery and inhibit the development of competence.

`NaN` is an old and bad way to encode what data scientists call a "missing value", or what database administrators might call a "null value". The fact that these `NaN` values ended up as *strings* `'nan'` in your data suggests that these `NaN` values were carelessly written to a data file, and then loaded back in as text.

Thus I will focus on properly re-encoding these `'nan'` strings as proper missing values. Then, your existing solution will more or less work as desired.

You must first convert your data to the correct data type. Historically, Pandas stored string data in an `'object'` dtype, which just meant "any arbitrary Python object", wherein null values were represented by the Python `None` object. This however is outdated, and now we have a proper `'string'` dtype, with a proper null value placeholder.

First we convert the `Name` and `State` columns to proper strings:

```py
df['Name'] = df['Name'].astype('string')
df['State'] = df['State'].astype('string')
```

You must do this manually, because Pandas uses "object" by default for backward compatibility. I hope that this default will change in some future version of Pandas (2.0?) but we are stuck with it for now.

Now, we can use one of several techniques to replace all instances of the string `'nan'` with a proper null value placeholder:

```py
# Option 1
df['Name'].mask(df['Name'] == 'nan', inplace=True)

# Option 2
df['Name'] = df['Name'].mask(df['Name'] == 'nan')

# Option 3
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'nan', 'Name'] = None
```

Then, the `.str.split` method will correctly propagate these null values forward, and you can use `.groupby('LastName', dropna=True)` as shown in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75558923/2954547).

Note that in the future, when reading data from CSV, you can (and should consider) using the `dtypes=` argument in order to set your desired data types up front. Consult [the docs for `read.csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for details on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you!  I really appreciate your help and the links!